# Is it possible to connect to MySQL without an IP address in the account name?

Tags: mysql

When I create a view, the `DEFINER` if that view is `foo`@`someip`.  Which means that if I lose the ability to connect from that IP address, I can no longer see the definition of that view.  I want `foo` to be able to see the view definition regardless of IP.

But I can't set `` DEFINER = `foo` `` because, according to the MySQL docs, either I have to have the `SET_USER_ID` privilege (which allows me to specify *any* account) or "Otherwise, the only permitted account is your own, specified either literally or as CURRENT_USER or CURRENT_USER(). You cannot set the definer to any other account."  ("Account" includes the hostname or IP address).

And I'm using shared hosting that obviously doesn't give me that privilege or any means to log in as `` `foo`@`localhost` ``.

I can't believe how stupid it is that MySQL works this way...

Is there any workaround besides obtaining a fixed IP/hostname to log in from?

Comment: Can you set the definer to `'foo'@'%'`?

Comment: @BillKarwin no.  As I already explained, I would have to have `SET_USER_ID` privilege to do that.  (Or the deprecated `SUPER` privilege on 5.7).  If I had this privilege I would be able to run stored procedure code as any user, so obviously my shared hosting won't give me this privilege.

Comment: I did find a way to log in as `foo`@`localhost`.  Compared to other database engines I've worked with, it's just bizarre that my view definition is locked down to a specific host.